# Google Custom Search retrieve all the results, is it possible?

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I'm starting to use the Google Custom Search Engine in order to retrieve a temporal use of some selected word in an online newspaper.
I see that for example my result provides a total of 22000 retrieved articles. I tried to retrieve pages after the 100 index but I can't get any result.
I also tried to search directly on the google web page, but I see that after the 10 page I can't go further, so this only show me the first 1000 result at max.
Does it is possible to retrieve every single result or I've to get just only a small portion of that?
Thanks